# what is the answer and why please "I'd rather you ...... to her why we can't go"?

Tags: grammar, tense

Would you please tell me why the answer is "explained" for the following question and why:

> I'd rather you ____________ to her why we can't go.
>
> 1-would explain
>
> 2-explained
>
> 3-to explain
>
> 4-will explain

Comment: Can you at least explain which ones you already know aren’t correct? Or which ones you suspected might be correct? Otherwise, this question may get closed  or downvoted due to a lack of research.

Comment: Or to put it bluntly: we are not going to do your homework for you..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, actually I need to know why the answer not "to explain ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sorry for the confusion, actually I need to know why the answer not "to explain "

The answer is not "to explain" because "would rather" takes the simple form of the verb - present simple when referring to your own actions, and past simple when referring to someone else's actions. (Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/would-rather-would-sooner).)

Sometimes, in everyday speech, the simple present is used as well - but not always, and the simple past is never wrong.